# How would I make this symbol? LaTeX

Tags: symbols, arrows, markdown

I know that my title was not very clear, but I do not know of any other way to describe this. I want to be able to write the following, and be able to change what letters are below the arrow:

[image]

Note: I have never used LaTeX, but the text editor that I am using supports it, and it seems to be my best bet. However if there is a better way to do it, I am not committed to LaTeX in any way.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say that your text editor supports LaTeX. It may have syntax highlighting and some buttons for running the compiler, but you will still need to install a TeX distribution (MiKTeX or TeXLive).

Comment: I am using https://typora.io/ and it says that this is the way I am supposed to write out math equations, that is the extent of my knowledge of LaTex.

Comment: OK, I see. You should be aware that it probably doesn't support everything in LaTeX. Most systems of this type only support a subset of its features.

Comment: @lan Thompson, Thanks for the advice! However I really don't need it for much other than taking simple notes on geometry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `\overleftrightarrow` command from the [amsmath package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\overleftrightarrow{YC}
\]
\end{document}
```